# how to add alert in to login my login page like "login successfully"?

Tags: codeigniter, authentication, alert

I have login page but i am dont know where i can take this alerts  ,

i will take my script like this

```
 echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'> window.alert('Your Login Succesfully ,'); window.location.href='home'; </SCRIPT>");
```

but i dont know how to make if else condition on my query in the model and contoller .I using num_rows but its didnt work .

my controller

```
public function login()
{
    $u = $this->input->post('username');
    $p = $this->input->post('password');
    $data = $this->app_model->getlogindata($u,$p);
    return $data;
}
```

my model

```
public function getlogindata($username,$password)
{
    $u = $username;
    $p = md5($password);

    $cek_login = $this->db->get_where('login', array('username' => $u,'password'=>$p));
    if(count($cek_login->result())>0)
    {
        foreach ($cek_login->result() as $qck)
        {
            if($qck->level=='puskesmas')
            {
                // $ambil_data = $this->db->get_where('puskesmas',array('id_puskesmas' => $u));
                $this->db->select('*');
                $this->db->from('puskesmas');
                $this->db->join('login', 'puskesmas.id_puskesmas=login.id_puskesmas');
                $this->db->where('username', $u);
                $ambil_data = $this->db->get(); 
                foreach ($ambil_data->result() as $qad)
                {
                    $sess_data['logged_in']         = 'yes';
                    $sess_data['id_puskesmas']      = $qad->id_puskesmas; //
                    $sess_data['nama_puskesmas']    = $qad->nama_puskesmas;
                    $sess_data['alamat_puskesmas']  = $qad->alamat_puskesmas;
                    $sess_data['nama_petugas']      = $qad->nama_petugas;
                    $sess_data['nomor']             = $qad->nomor;
                    $sess_data['email']             = $qad->email;
                    $sess_data['level']             = $qad->level;
                    $this->session->set_userdata($sess_data);
                }
                header('location:'.base_url().'puskesmas');
            } //xammp mu aktif?

            elseif($qck->level=='dinas')
            {
                //$ambil_data = $this->db->get_where('dinas',array('id_dinas' => $u));
                $this->db->select('*');
                $this->db->from('dinas');
                $this->db->join('login', 'dinas.id_dinas=login.id_dinas');
                $this->db->where('username', $u);
                $ambil_data = $this->db->get(); 
                foreach ($ambil_data->result() as $qad)
                {
                    $sess_data['logged_in']         = 'yes';
                    $sess_data['id_dinas']          = $qad->id_dinas;
                    $sess_data['nama_dinas']        = $qad->nama_dinas;
                    $sess_data['alamat_dinas']      = $qad->alamat_dinas;
                    $sess_data['kode_pos']          = $qad->kode_pos;
                    $sess_data['level']             = $qad->level;
                    $this->session->set_userdata($sess_data);
                }
                header('location:'.base_url().'dinas');
            }
            elseif($qck->level=='admin')
            {
                //$ambil_data = $this->db->get_where('admin',array('id_admin' => $u));
                $this->db->select('*');
                $this->db->from('admin');
                $this->db->join('login', 'admin.id_admin=login.id_admin');
                $this->db->where('username', $u);
                $ambil_data = $this->db->get(); 
                foreach ($ambil_data->result() as $qad)
                {
                    $sess_data['logged_in']         = 'yes';
                    $sess_data['id_admin']          = $qad->id_admin;
                    $sess_data['nama_admin']        = $qad->nama_admin;
                    $sess_data['alamat_admin']      = $qad->alamat_admin;
                    $sess_data['status']            = $qad->status;
                    $sess_data['level']             = $qad->level;
                    $this->session->set_userdata($sess_data);
                }
                header('location:'.base_url().'admin');
            }
            else{

                echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'> window.alert('Record Updated Successfully'); window.location.href='web'; </SCRIPT>");// i add this and still didnt work
            }
        }

    }
}
```

in this script i just didnt know where i can take this alerts and what a parameter can i use to add this alerts . like if num_rows = 1 , echo = blablabla
thanks you sir

Answer (score 1):

you have to use flash data in code igniter or you can use ajax callback in success you can alert what you want and redirect to whatever you like.

**Controller**

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('error_message', 'Incorrect Username or Password ! Please try again.');
            redirect(URL.'backend/login');
```

**View**

```
<?php
            if ($this->session->flashdata('error_message')) 
            {
        ?>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" style="color: #fff;">
                    <!-- <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button> -->
                    <span><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('error_message'); ?></span>
                </div>
        <?php
            }

            if ($this->session->flashdata('ok_message')) 
            {
        ?>
                <div class="alert alert-success">
                    <!-- <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button> -->
                    <span><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('ok_message'); ?></span>
                </div>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: ok if i use session flashdata in my controller  i need a if else logic ? and this View i need to add on all view ? or how ?

Comment: @AdhikMulat you have to store some data into session after u login successfully then u can use session flash data and redirect it will load the page and will show the flash data error or message but u must add the code in each view in the top where u want to show the error

Answer (score 0):

try this.i hope it will help you.

```
else{
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("Record Updated Successfully")';
window.location.href = 'web';
echo '</script>';
}
```